# Kinesis data analytics sql application is not writing logs into cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I created a kinesis data analytics application(using SQL) and attached cloudwatch logging option.
when i run the application, i am receiving the result based on my requirements.

**Problem: my kinesis-data-analytics application is not writing logs into cloudwatch.**

**Note: I used CloudWatch FullAccess policy. The configured cloudwatch log-group and stream-name are also correct.**

Please let me know how can i receive the logs.

Regards,

Siva

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Hi  PatrykMilewski,

At present, kinesis data analytics application only supports to write ERROR LOGGING MESSAGES, that too SPECIFIC APPLICATION CONFIGURATION ERROR MESSAGES.

here is the info from aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/cloudwatch-logs.html